# Can I VPN connect to my work using Windows 8?

Tags: vpn, windows-domain, windows-8

Windows 8 comes in a few versions ... with two of them being

- Windows 8
- Windows 8 Pro

Checking the [comparison chart on wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions#Comparison_chart), the pro feature has this (where the non-pro doesn't)..

*Can join a Windows domain?* **Windows 8: no**. Windows 8 Pro: yes.

*Group Policy?* **Windows 8: no**. Windows 8 Pro: yes.

Currently, when I Vpn from my Windows 7 machine to work I need to provide my *domain/username* and *password*.

Does this mean I can't do this with Windows 8 and I need to purchase the Windows 8 Pro edition?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 Home Premium which doesn't support joining Windows  Server domains, and I can connect to the work VPN just fine - I guess this will be that way in Windows 8 as well. Basically, joining a domain means (amongst a whole load of other things) being able to use the domain/username to log into your computer, not into remote computers. (In fact, if you were logged into that domain account on your local machine, you probably wouldn't need to log into the VPN with them anymore if your IT set things up to support this.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. It will work from Windows 8 as well without Pro version because you are providing domain credentials to VPN connection not to log into your machine.

Those two features mean that your machine could be part of Windows domain in your own network and managed through group policies.